# CKEditor icons not showing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I just updated my ckeditor_rails gem version from 4.5.3 to 4.17.0. And it works, but icons in the panel are not showing. I found out, that it looks for paths like these:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisahttp://localhost:3000/icons.png?t=c08cfedb60
```

So the problem is, that some preprocessor (or something like that) adds host url `http://localhost:3000` before path to the image file `/icons.png?t=c08cfedb60`. Ckeditor::Rails::AssetUrlProcessor than prepends it with path to ckeditor template `http://localhost:3000/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa`. What could be the cause of such url manipulation in css file? Is there something that edits css url paths?

App uses:
Rails 4.2,
CKEditor 4.19,
gem ckeditor_rails 4.17

I have set `var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/assets/ckeditor/";` and `Ckeditor::Rails.config.assets_base_path = "/assets/ckeditor"`

Comment: I hotfixed it by editing the ckeditor source code css for every icon like this: `.cke_button__about_icon { background: url(/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/icons.png?t=c08cfedb60) no-repeat 0 -0px !important; }`. I added this to view, where I use the editor. It's not ideal, but it works for now..